# Issues on getting event from Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883938/getting-events-from-calendar) code to get event from calendar.

But I got **error** like this:

```
request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

When debugging I noticed that code crash on this line:

```
Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver
                    .query(builder.build(), new String[]
                    { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay" },
                            "Calendars._id=" + 1, null,
                            "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");

 System.out.println("eventCursor count=" + eventCursor.getCount());
```

any idea will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred for the OS version. May be you are using SDK-7. try this code instead,

```
Uri.Builder builder;
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7)
      {
       // the old way
       builder = Uri.parse("content://calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
      } else
      {
       // the new way
       builder = Uri
         .parse("content://com.android.calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
      }
```

This should work fine.