# Android get calendar event

Tags: android, calendar

I tried to run code from this post: (
[Getting events from calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883938/getting-events-from-calendar) )
In order to get event from my mail account.

Unfortunatly, it recognizes my accounts but can't get any events. I triple checked, and I do have events on my calendar.

Where could the problem be?

Comment: [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) might helpful for you.

Comment: I was also working on this one but it seems I can't get it work, at all. Like it has 5 deprecated lines and one not working etc ....