# Retrieving Data from android calendar through id

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have **`ID`** of an event. Now I want to retrieve other details of that event. How can I get details of the event?

```
public static long getNewEventId(ContentResolver cr, Uri cal_uri)
{
    Uri local_uri = cal_uri;
    if (cal_uri == null)
    {
        // local_uri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars/" +
        // "events");
        local_uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(local_uri,
            new String[] { "MAX(_id) as max_id" }, null, null, "_id");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long max_val = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("max_id"));
    return max_val;
}
```

Using this, I get the ID of last event added. Now I want all the details of this event using this ID.

Comment: What have you code? Add more details to your question if you want an appropriate and quick answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883938/getting-events-from-calendar check this