# Issue with fetching details from Google calendar android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am developing an android app where I am trying to fetch event details from the users Google calendar.I have refered this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883938/getting-events-from-calendar?answertab=votes#tab-top) and its working fine, on all other phones , except few galaxy phones(like Galaxy S). I am not sure what could be the problem.

Please help! Thanks!