# getting issue in fetching event from android calendar, some time cursor got event or some time cursor did not get events

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I want event from android calendar specific date wise of arrayList. but getting issue some time cursor of getting event show 0 result and some time its show prefect result. help show my following code and help me.

loop for arrayList for fetching specific date wise event

```
for (int i = 0; i < mListCalendarData.size(); i++) {
           readCalendarEvent(mHomeActivity, mSharedPreferencesCustom.getString(SharedPreferencesConstant.PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, ""),
                        getYearOnly(mListCalendarData.get(i).getDate()),
                        getMonthOnly(mListCalendarData.get(i).getDate()),
                        getDateOnly(mListCalendarData.get(i).getDate()),
                        getHoursOnly(mListCalendarData.get(i).getTime()),
                        getMinteOnly(mListCalendarData.get(i).getTime()),
                        getAOnly(mListCalendarData.get(i).getTime()),
                        mListCalendarData.get(i).getTitle());
            }
```

this is function for read calendar event.

```
public boolean readCalendarEvent(final Context context, final String AccountName, final int year, final int month, final int date, final int hours, final int mint, final int A, final String APITitle) {
        isEventAdded = false;
                try {
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
                    String[] projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.OWNER_ACCOUNT, CalendarContract.Events._ID, CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION};

                    Calendar c_start = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c_start.set(year, month, date, 01, 00, 00); //Note that months start from 0 (January)

                    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    endTime.set(year, month, date, 23, 59, 59);

                    String selection = "(( " +CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID +" == "+calId+" ) AND (" + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + c_start.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " <= " + endTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( deleted != 1 ))";
                    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), projection, selection, null, "dtstart ASC");

                            System.out.println("Cursor size====================>" + cursor.getCount());
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {

                                    Log.i("CalanderStaff", "CALENDAR_ID: " + cursor.getString(0));
                                    Log.i("CalanderStaff", "title: " + cursor.getString(1));
                                    Log.i("CalanderStaff", "CalendarTime: " +cursor.getString(3));
                                    Log.i("CalanderStaff", "Account : " + cursor.getString(5));
                                    Log.i("CalanderStaff", "ID : " + cursor.getString(6));
                                    Log.i("CalanderStaff", "Our account : " + AccountName);
                                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                            } else {

                                Log.i("CalanderStaff", "No event for this date ..  cursor 0");
                            }
                            cursor.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return true;
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue. thank you.

Comment: Try using the code from the [documentUsing intents to view calendar data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view) using Calendar Provider.You might also want to check this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175930/5995040) for a more specific example regarding getting the calendar events from android calendar. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thank for ans. i tried all most all ex related with specific date getting even. but mostly all have this issue